# sanitize url is not rendering in iframe

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

i have a service which return video urls in a format like [url1,url2,...]
as these are unsafe url so sanitize them in the loop.

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { HomeService } from '../home/home.service'
    import { BrowserModule, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'
    import { SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    videoCollection: string[] = [];
    videoCollectionSafe: SafeResourceUrl[];

    constructor(private homseService: HomeService, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
        this.homseService.getVideos().subscribe((response) => this.videoCollection = response.json());

        for (var i = 0; i < this.videoCollection.length; i++) {
            this.videoCollectionSafe.push(sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.videoCollection[i]));
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

in html i write

```
  <!--<li *ngFor="let obj of videoCollectionSafe"><iframe width="560" height="315" [src]="obj" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>-->
 <li *ngFor="let obj of videoCollectionSafe">{{obj}}</li>
```

both lines are not working.it displays nothing on page. can somebody help me out of this.

Comment: Side-note: don't just add by rote `implements OnInit` and the an empty `ngOnInit()`. If the class it doesn't implement it, don't add it. That said, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lesimoes is partly correct in that you should use the life-cycle hook and not the constructor.

The bigger problem is that you try to iterate on the list *before* it's been received. Observable Subscriptions are asynchronous, just like any AJAX call. So you have to act on the data after you get it back. Simply putting the lines of code after the AJAX call won't do it.

For that you have two options.

Do so in the [`onComplete` handler](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html):

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    videoCollection: string[] = [];
    videoCollectionSafe: SafeResourceUrl[] = [];

    constructor(private homseService: HomeService, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        this.homseService.getVideos().subscribe(
            response => this.videoCollection = response,
            error => console.error(error),
            () => this.videoCollection.forEach(video => this.videoCollectionSafe.push(sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(video)))
        );
    }
}
```

Or more "functionally" in the `onNext` handler, since you don't need the intermediary `videoCollection` member at all, it seems:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    videoCollectionSafe: SafeResourceUrl[] = [];

    constructor(private homseService: HomeService, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.homseService.getVideos().subscribe(
            videoCollection => videoCollection.forEach(video =>  this.videoCollectionSafe.push(sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(video)))
            error => console.error(error)
        );
    }
}
```

Also, you haven't stated which version of angular you're using, but if it's after 4.3 you don't need to cast `response.json()` [because `HttpClient` will do that for you](https://angular.io/guide/http). If you're running a version of Angular so old that you still have the old `Http` you should seriously consider upgrading, as 6.0.0 was released yesterday.

Comment: @SumitSharma If the answer solved your problem, you can close the question by clicking the check-mark next to this (or any better) answer.

Answer (score -1):

Move your code to ngOnInit(). Check this about Angular lifecycle: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

videoCollection: string[] = [];
videoCollectionSafe: SafeResourceUrl[];

constructor(private homseService: HomeService, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {   }

ngOnInit() {

    this.homseService.getVideos().subscribe((response) => 
    this.videoCollection = response.json());

    for (var i = 0; i < this.videoCollection.length; i++) {         this.videoCollectionSafe.push(sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.videoCollection[i]));
    }

}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because you're looping over `this.videoCollection` _before_ it's set because it's outside the Observable subscription.

Comment: so cant we loop over a collection which holdes the value and sanitize them later. can you provide me with a solution

Comment: Its right, my bad. But @msanford edit my answer before, could you change the parentheses position and give a solution... Or not?

Comment: @lesimoes Part of the purpose of voting is to get good answers (and to show mistakes in answers). You can **absolutely** [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50175382/edit) your answer and fix the problem and the votes might change. :) I get down-voted all the time when I make mistakes.

Comment: @msanford i`m totally agree with your down vote, but this comunity is about colaborate to improve members, if you know the answer why not provide with a edit?

Comment: @lesimoes Fair question. It's not allowed to edit someone else's post for _content,_ just for _formatting_, which is what I did, (or to lend a hand if someone accidentally posted a password or something). When you get higher reputation, you'll have access to the Edit Review Queue, and you'll see that "attempt to respond" is a reason to _deny_ a suggested edit for that reason. We're expected to discuss issues in comments. Just how the community has decided to operate.